# Is it possible to peek at the next rand value

Tags: c, random

Assuming the generator has been seeded, it is possible to peek at the next random value without changing it?

i.e. given:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int r;
r = rand(); // say this is 99
r = rand(); // say this is 80
```

Is this possible

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int r;
r = peekAtRand(); // this will give 99
r = rand(); // but this still gives 99

r = peekAtRand(); // this will give 80
r = rand(); // but this still gives 80
```

Furthermore, can this be extended to peeking at the next **n numbers**?

Comment: Why not use `r = rand();` , test it using a condition and then, do things appropriately?

Comment: You can buffer the random numbers with eg a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Comment: How is rand() seeded?

Comment: That would defeat the purpose of `rand`. Peek a few numbers, run password generator, profit

Comment: There's no standard function to do what you want. You could create your own wrapper around rand() though that caches the next value and let you peek at it. @MattMcNabb No, it would not defeat the purpose of rand().

Comment: If you know n-1....n...n+1 and so on, what is random in that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement `peekAtRand` as follows:

```
int peekAtRand()
{
    int r,s;
    s = rand();
    srand(s);
    r = rand();
    srand(s);
    return r;
}
```

To make it "worthy", call `srand((unsigned int)time(NULL))` at the beginning of your program.

Comment: Bad, since you can't call it multiple times and get the same value in each call.

Comment: @CássioRenan: 1. Where does that requirement appear in the question??? For the code given in the question, this function does the job exactly as defined by the user. 2. You actually **can** get the same value multiple times, you just don't know when that might happen (which is a basic purpose of `rand()` as far as I'm aware of).

Comment: This is exactly what i was after!

Comment: @barakmanos 1. If you "peek" something, you expect it to not change its state. Since by peeking twice you get different results, the state is clearly changing. 2. That's just you being defensive. You know what I'm talking about.

Comment: @CássioRenan: 1. This would be true if that state was something deterministic. In the case of `rand()`, this state is not deterministic **by definition** (i.e., you're not supposed to know, or even guess with good probability, what that state is). 2. No, I'm not being defensive, and no - I honestly have no idea what you're talking about. If I understand you correctly, then you're saying that `peekAtRand` cannot generate the same value consecutively several times. But that is also true for `rand` (more precisely, they both can, but with very low probability). So I don't understand your point.

Comment: `rand()` uses a pseudo-random engine to generate numbers, so it **is** deterministic.
You're mixing "state" with "output".
Even if the output was not deterministic(it is), the state is: all PRNG engines have an internal state, and with the same state, the next number generated will always be the same.
Think of an input buffer: The output is not deterministic (it depends on whatever produced the input), but the state (current buffer content) is.
I'm going to stop discussing now, since this is not getting anywere, but please feel free to answer this comment.

Comment: @CássioRenan: Of course it is deterministic. Just like any other executable code that runs on a deterministic machine (which at this point is the only type of machines that our technology has to offer). But `rand` has the purpose of being **seemingly** as non-deterministic as possible. In other words, it has a deterministic cycle, but that cycle completes only after a few billion iterations, so it goes "unnoticed", giving you a good-enough illusion of randomness. And that behavior is (I suppose) what OP wanted to be provided by `peekAtRand`.

Comment: This is really a bad idea. Sure, it works, but its a clearly misuse of the `srand` function.

Comment: @Flovdis: First of all, that's what OP has asked for, so it doesn't matter whether or not `srand` is used for its original purpose. Second, `srand` provides an interface for seeding the random number generator. It doesn't tell you when or where to use it, so you can "tweak" your code in any way you like while using it. The code I provided in my solution perhaps "weakens the randomness", but that is bound to happen **by definition**. In other words, if you "peek into a random value", then don't expect it to be "very" random afterwards. Having said that, please revoke your down-vote!!!

Comment: @barakmanos I disagree. OP especially asked for a solution to peeking at the next n numbers. Your solution lacks this extensibility. Also your solution will lead to problems with parallel programming. My down-vote expresses my disagreement with your solution, in my opinion your answer probably looks simple, but it's a hack and not useful.

Comment: @Flovdis: As I said, once you "peek into `rand`", you make it "hacky" **by definition**. It was also explained to OP in the comments to his or her question. Surprisingly enough, it is **exactly** what he or she wanted (check out OP's comment to this answer, third one from the top). Now I'm asking you again - please revoke your down-vote!

Comment: NEVER, EVER, EVER, put srand() inside the loop. You're not getting random numbers at all!

Comment: This will also fail on any RNG where the domain of srand() of not identical to the range of rand(), and yes they do exist. I regret that I only have one downvote.

Comment: @barakmanos Please keep conversations civil in the future, and relevant to the information in the post being commented on. There are [real people on the receiving end of all comments](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/internet_argument.png).

Comment: @JasonC: I did try to, honestly. I even explained why "peeking into `rand()`" as OP asked would revoke the randomness of this function **by definition** (a comment which you have deleted as I now see). That other user ignored it and continued bashing at me. In addition, and although not a perfect excuse for making an uncivilized conversation, if you followed those last few comments which you deleted, then you'd notice that I wasn't the one who started it.

Comment: @barakmanos I do not have the power to delete comments. They were either deleted by a moderator or automatically deleted after receiving more than a certain number of flags. Unfortunately, you will never be able to construct a solid argument that justifies stating assumptions about how another person was treated by others in their past in civil discourse about random number generation, nor will you be able to claim that calling somebody names (even if they called you names first, which I do not know) is the right thing to do. I suspect this is not the first time you have been told to be nice.

Answer (score 7):

This is not possible with the current implementation of most random number generators. But there are two solutions for this.

### Solution 1

If you set the start value of the random number generator using the `srand()` function to the same value, you will always get the same sequence of numbers. This way you can easily predict the number in a second pass.

### Solution 2

Simple write a small buffer for the numbers.

```
const int randBufferSize = 1024;
int randBuffer[randBufferSize];
int randBufferPosition = 0;

// Initialise the buffer with random data.
void initRandBuffer() {
    for (int i = 0; i < randBufferSize; ++i) {
        randBuffer[i] = rand();
    }
}

// Peek at the n'th random number (starting from 0).
int peekAtRand(int n) {
    int peekIndex = randBufferPosition + n;
    if (peekIndex >= randBufferSize) {
        peekIndex -= randBufferSize;
    }
    return randBuffer[peekIndex];
}

// Get the next random number.
int getRand() {
    int result = randBuffer[randBufferPosition];
    randBuffer[randBufferPosition] = rand();
    ++randBufferPosition;
    if (randBufferPosition >= randBufferPosition) {
        randBufferPosition = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
int peek;
int r;

peek = rand();
doPeekyThings(peek);
r = peek;
```

Comment: If this was too easy, I'm sure someone can come up with a way to obfuscate it to oblivion with 10k LOC.

Answer (score 2):

> Assuming the generator has been seeded, it is possible to peek at the next random value without changing it?

Not using `rand()` by itself. You need to buffer it.

> Furthermore, can this be extended to peeking at the next n numbers?

If you buffer it, then yes:

```
const int bufsize = 15;
int randarr[bufsize];
int cur_rand = 0;

int my_srand(int seed) {
  srand(seed);
  for (int i=0;i<bufsize;++i) {
    randarr[i] = rand();
  }
}

int my_rand() {
  int r = randarr[cur_rand];
  randarr[cur_rand] = rand();
  ++cur_rand;
  if (cur_rand >= bufsize) cur_rand = 0;
  return  r;
}

int peek_my_rand(int n = 0) {
  return randarr[(cur_rand + n)%bufsize];
}
```

With this implementation, you always have `bufsize` numbers to peek at, and peeking will never mess with the actual generator, meaning it will never change its internal state.